# where and how to write pre/post query action in redwoodJS?

Tags: prisma, redwoodjs

I'm in my first days on learning redwoodJS.
I'm just jump in from Django.

All I know, redwood web app flow like this :
web-client will call the API (apollo graphQL),
API side is a Prisma-Client.

In Django, we can write a 'signal' that will be called pre/post query.
I.e : pre-delete, post-delete, pre-add, post-add,etc etc.
Signal is 'attached' in models.py

My question : is there any doc that elaborate on how and where to write that 'signal' in RedwoodJS?

Looks like Prisma have 'middleware' approach for this, but i don't know where and how to do it in redwoodJS.

Sincerely

-bino-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Redwood API directory includes Services, used by your GraphQL API or any other place in your backend code. A Service function typically imports the `db` object, which is the Prisma Client. From there, you can use Prisma Middleware. Here are a couple of related links.

Redwood Services:
https://redwoodjs.com/docs/services

Prisma Middleware:
https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/middleware